# Connecting separate WordPress Docker-Compose Stacks to an external MySQL and phpMyAdmin Containers

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, containers

How to achieve the following with docker-compose:

- Have a separate container for each WordPress environment.
- A single container dedicated for MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm still new to docker, and I couldn't find the answer online. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up MySQL and phpMyAdmin:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    #Database
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        ports: 
            - "1207:3306"
        restart: always
        container_name: my_wordpress_db
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password


    #phpMyAdmin
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        container_name: my_wordpress_phpmyadmin
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        environment: 
            PMA_HOST: db:3306
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

volumes: 
    db_data:

networks:
    default:
        external: 
            name: my_wordpress_network
```

Setting up the WordPress docker environment:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    #Wordpress
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress:latest
        external_links: 
            - my_wordpress_db:db
        volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
        ports:
            - "33003:80"
        restart: always
        container_name: my_project_container
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_project_db

networks:
    default:
        external: 
            name: my_wordpress_network
```